# How to reset DNS to its default after changing it with systemd-resolve?

Tags: networking, systemd, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04. AFAIK, DNS could be changed with `sudo systemd-resolve -i wlp3s0 --set-dns="xxx-yyy-aaa-bbb"`.
Now, how can I revert it back to the default state? Before setting it, my DNS was set to `192.168.1.1` (or router).

I want to make a script out of these commands so preferably no GUI.  Also I'm looking for the most generic and "standardized" way so no CLI front-ends for GUI apps (like nmcli) or the like.
Also it seems, disconnecting from router and reconnecting, sets it to the default state...but I think there should be a better way....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about making a default-resolve.conf file and setting the script to write that default-resolve.conf to resolve.conf whenever you want to reset it.

You could then create a script 'resetdns' which only runs:
cp etc/default-resolve.conf etc/resolve.conf

It would probably need to be run with sudo, but that should resolve your problem.

Also, the systemd-resolve [main page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved) (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-resolved) offers some interesting information, you could add resolvectl status to the end of your 'resetdns' script to have it verify that it's been reset.